# Sum the total number of lines of code in all tar files in all subdirectories

Tags: linux, bash, files, tar

I would like to calculate the sum of the total number of lines of all tar files in all subdirectories.

Consider the following example directory, `se-example`:

```
se-example
├── directory1
│   ├── archive1.tar
│   └── archive2.tar
└── directory2
    ├── README.txt
    ├── archive3.tar
    └── directory3
        └── archive4.tar
```

To recreate this example, consider the following:

```
echo "create and enter example"
mkdir se-example
cd se-example

echo "create example directory 1 (w/ two tar files)"
mkdir directory1
cd directory1

echo "create example tar 1 [+7 lines]"
mkdir archive1
printf "Line 1 \n Line 2" >> archive1/README.txt
printf "Line 1 \n Line 2" >> archive1/code1.py
printf "Line 1 \n Line 2 \n Line 3" >> archive1/code2.py
tar -cf archive1.tar archive1
rm -rf archive1 

echo "create example tar 2 [+5 lines]"
mkdir archive2 
printf "Line 1 \n Line 2 \n Line 3" >> archive2/code1.py
printf "Line 1 \n Line 2" >> archive2/code2.py
tar -cf archive2.tar archive2
rm -rf archive2

cd ..

echo "create example directory 1 (w/ subdirectory, readme, and two tar files)"
mkdir directory2
cd directory2

echo "create example readme [+0 lines]"
printf "Line 1 \n Line 2" >> README.txt

echo "create example tar 3 [+1 line]"
mkdir archive3 
printf "Line 1" >> archive3/code1.py
tar -cf archive3.tar archive3
rm -rf archive3

echo "create example subdirectory (w/ one tar file)"
mkdir directory3
cd directory3

echo "create example tar 4 [+5 lines]"
mkdir archive4
printf "Line 1 \n Line 2 \n Line 3" >> archive4/code1.py
printf "Line 1 \n Line 2" >> archive4/code2.py
tar -cf archive4.tar archive4
rm -rf archive4

cd ..
cd ..
cd ..

echo "done creating example"
```

In this example, there are four tar files with a total of 18 lines (7 lines in tar 1, 5 lines in tar 2, 1 line in tar 3, and 5 lines in tar 4). The correct answer would give 18.

I know how to count the number of tar files ([suggested here](https://superuser.com/questions/474334/count-of-files-in-each-sub-directories)):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d | while read dir; do
  printf "%-25.25s : " "$dir"
  find "$dir" -name "*.tar" | wc -l
done
```

I know how to count the number of lines of code in individual tar files ([suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23594009/how-to-count-the-number-of-files-inside-a-tar-gz-file-without-decompressing)):

```
tar -tf se-example/directory1/archive1.tar | wc -l
```

How do I combine these two commands, or is there an efficient alternative that will solve this problem?

Comment: Why not just `find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type f -name *.tar | xargs -n1 tar tf >> file.txt` and then `awk 'END{print NR}' file.txt`? It will give an error message but it will still append all of the lines to the file.

Comment: Maybe I am not understanding correctly. Executing `find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type f -name "*.tar" | xargs -n1 tar tf >> file.txt` yields an empty file.

Comment: Perhaps your environment is different. When I run that same command, it prints the lines to the file with an error at the end(I was running it before without `-name *.tar`. I had to escape the asterisk to get it to expand and this command: `find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -name \*.tar | xargs -n1 tar tf >> file.txt` outputs all of the lines to file.txt and `awk 'END{print NR}' file.txt` prints the number of records or lines just like the first command but with no errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the newline `\n` for the last line in each of your test files, so the count of `wc` is actually less:

```
$ find . \( -name "*.py" -o -name "README*" \) -print0 | xargs -0 wc -l
  1 ./directory1/archive1/README.txt
  1 ./directory1/archive1/code1.py
  2 ./directory1/archive1/code2.py
  2 ./directory1/archive2/code1.py
  1 ./directory1/archive2/code2.py
  1 ./directory2/README.txt
  0 ./directory2/archive3/code1.py
  2 ./directory2/directory3/archive4/code1.py
  1 ./directory2/directory3/archive4/code2.py
 11 total
```

Since `/directory2/README.txt` is not in an archive, we have 10 lines in total.

1. List the files in the archives:

   ```
   $ find . -name "*.tar" -print0 | xargs -0I{} tar tf {}
   archive1/
   archive1/README.txt
   archive1/code1.py
   archive1/code2.py
   archive2/
   archive2/code1.py
   archive2/code2.py
   archive3/
   archive3/code1.py
   archive4/
   archive4/code1.py
   archive4/code2.py
   ```
2. Extract the files to stdout with the `-O` / `--to-stdout` option:

   ```
   $ find . -name "*.tar" -print0 | xargs -0I{} tar xOf {}
   Line 1
    Line 2Line 1
    Line 2Line 1
    Line 2
    Line 3Line 1
    Line 2
    Line 3Line 1
    Line 2Line 1Line 1
    Line 2
    Line 3Line 1
    Line 2
   ```

   (The last line `Line 2` has no newline)
3. Count the lines with `wc`:

   ```
   $ find . -name "*.tar" -print0 | xargs -0I{} tar xOf {} | wc -l
   10
   ```

Comment: Works at about 20 minutes to read 76615873 lines. Thanks!

Comment: What if we wanted to only count the lines in the python files?

Comment: GNU `tar` has a `--wildcards` option to match member names of the archive: `... | xargs -0I{} tar xOf {} --wildcards '*.py' | wc -l`